# Delete ^Mnull characters in file

Tags: bash, null, character, erase

is just that i am trying to use sed and awk  in a file to get columns, but i only get the first element of the column, i checked with cat and less and i found that all lines at the end have the ^Mnull character, i dont know what difference does it have with the null character, i only know it shows ^Mnull.

```
8%    |**                             |   978k 00:00:42 ETA^Mnull                  
10%   |***                            |  1229k 00:00:40 ETA^Mnull
```

How could i erase it in bash?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The linked question is about a file which is opened in VIM. VIM is interactive, so the answers in the linked question don't apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr -d '\000\r' < yourfile > newfile
```

**Notes**:

The "-d" says to *delete* rather than *transpose* which is *tr*'s normal modus operandi

The "\000" represents null.

The "\r" represents carriage return characters.

The order of the characters to delete is unimportant - they are just deleted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it is not working, i still get ^Mnull at the end, and because of that, awk only shows the first element of the column i need, not the complete column. i dont know what else to do to erase it.

Comment: Try using "tr" as per edit.